# Auto Generated Code For Specific Fields (yii)

Tags: yii

I am using gii to auto generate crud function. But i do not want it for all the fields. I want it to work for specific fields:

for example
user_id(auto increment)
firstName
lastName
email
validate

now i dot want to put value using form in user_id and validate field. I do not want to view these fields in the form. Because these are either auto generated or operational fields. And general users does not need to know about it. So, like how to do this using gii.

Answer (score 3):

modify the gii generated form and the omitted fields will not appear in the crud form.

Comment: please explain how to modify the gii generated form to ommit the fields, thank you